# Python 3.2 Pyside 1.0.8 какое заклинание нужно?

Tags: python, windows

Возник вопрос. Нужно заюзать `PySide` под `Python 3.2`, но увы не хватает знаний древних заклинаний, чтобы осознать то, что нужно. На своем сайте `PySide Team` [опубликовали запись](http://www.pyside.org/2011/10/pyside-1-0-8-adios-coxinha-released/).

Почитал про [Shiboken](http://www.pyside.org/docs/shiboken/). Узнал, что это генератор биндов и так далее.

Сижу, и не могу понять, что откуда нужно скачать и заколдовать, чтобы все заработало. А заработать оно должно под Windows, потому как под Linux оно как-то должно собираться (судя по расширениям файлов Шибокена).

Просветите темноту, не могу сообразить, что к чему)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С недавних пор, с версии 1.1.0, если быть точным, команда PySide начала делать прекомпилированные бинарники для windows/python 3.2. Взять можно [тут](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Windows).